# Instability with the Sherman Morrison Woodbury Formula?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I am currently undertaking research which involves the use of the Sherman Morrison Woodbury formula for matrix inversion.
\begin{align*}
&(A + UWV^*)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(W^{-1}+V^*A^{-1}U)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}\\
&(A + UWV^*)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}UW(I+V^*A^{-1}UW)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}
\end{align*}
Where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $V^*\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$, $D\in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ and $U\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$.

Curiously, when computing this numerically for say $n=3$ and $r=2$,
\begin{align*}
(A + UWV^*)^{-1} &\approx A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(W^{-1}+V^*A^{-1}U)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}\\
&\approx A^{-1} - A^{-1}UW(I+V^*A^{-1}UW)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}
\end{align*}

However, when increasing $n$ to say 1000, computing $(A + UWV^*)^{-1}$ is vastly different from $A^{-1} - A^{-1}UW(I+V^*A^{-1}UW)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}$ and $A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(W^{-1}+V^*A^{-1}U)^{-1}V^*A^{-1}$.

I was wondering if these are results I should be expecting? If so, is there any relevant material for computing these formulas in numerically stable fashion. Or perhaps my implementation is wrong?

Comment: The instability mainly comes from the evaluation of $A^{-1}$, If your $A$ is a nice matrix, I do not see any issue with SMW.